# How to send multiple post request using jmeter and json array?

Tags: json, jmeter

I have this path in jmeter:

```
ctn_v2/wr/?${sid}&${pid}&f&${messageNumber}&${streamId}&${streamMessageId}&${dataFlagType}&subsid=${subsId}
```

what I want to do is to send multiple post request with different parameters using HTTP request with Jmeter.
I am taking the parameters from JSON file which contain JSON array which each item in the JSON array has values which I want to send in a different post request.
I used JSON path extractor to extract the values as follows (taken from DEBUG post sampler):

```
messageNumber_0=[0,1,2,4,3,5,6,7,8]
messageNumber_1=0
messageNumber_2=1
messageNumber_3=2
messageNumber_4=4
messageNumber_5=3
messageNumber_6=5
messageNumber_7=6
messageNumber_8=7
messageNumber_9=8
messageNumber_matchNr=9
msgSize=10
pid=2
protocol=https
sid=1600385571504156
streamId=[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
streamId_1=0
streamId_2=1
streamId_3=1
streamId_4=0
streamId_5=0
streamId_6=0
streamId_7=0
streamId_8=0
streamId_9=0
streamId_matchNr=9
streamMessageId=[0,0,1,2,1,3,4,5,6]
streamMessageId_1=0
streamMessageId_2=0
streamMessageId_3=1
streamMessageId_4=2
streamMessageId_5=1
streamMessageId_6=3
streamMessageId_7=4
streamMessageId_8=5
streamMessageId_9=6
```

I want to be able to send the 1st post request with messageNUmber_0, streamId_0, etc... I tried to use 'counter' to resolve it but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can organize your Test Plan as follows:

- [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller): condition `${__javaScript(${counter} < ${messageNumber_matchNr},)}`

  - [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter): starting value `1`, Increment `1`, Reference Name: `counter`
  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

In the HTTP Request sampler you can refer respective item names as:

- `${__V(messageNumber_${counter})}`
- `${__V(streamId_${counter})}`
- and `${__V(streamMessageId_${counter})}`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Combine Variables]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)